# How do you pass boost::bind objects to a function?

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I have a one-dimensional function minimizer.  Right now I'm passing it function pointers.  However many functions have multiple parameters, some of which are held fixed.  I have implemented this using functors like so

```
template <class T>
minimize(T &f) {
}

Functor f(param1, param2);
minimize<Functor>(f);
```

However the functor definition has lots of crud.  Boost::bind looks cleaner.  So that I could do:

```
minimize(boost:bind(f,_1,param1,param2))
```

However I'm not clear what my `minimize` declaration should like like using `boost::bind`.  What type of object is `boost::bind`?  Is there an easy pattern for this that avoids the boilerplate of functors but allows multiple parameter binding?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just use `boost::function`. I think `boost::bind` does have its own return type, but that is compatible with `boost::function`. Typical use is to make a typedef for the function:

```
typedef boost::function<bool(std::string)> MyTestFunction;
```

and then you can pass any compatible function with `boost::bind`:

```
bool SomeFunction(int i, std::string s) { return true; }
MyTestFunction f = boost::bind(SomeFunction, 42, _1);
f("and then call it.");
```

I hope that is what you want.

It also works with methods by passing the `this` pointer for the call as second parameter to `boost::bind`.

Answer (score 4):

I would define minimize() this way:

```
minimize(boost::function< return_type(param_type1,param_type2,param_type3,...)> f)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you could call minimize() like this:

```
minimize(boost::bind(&class::function,actual_object,_1,_2,_3,...));
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the parameter to a value parameter. Function objects are intentionally light weight, and `boost::bind` certainly is, specially crafted to fit in within space of a few bytes using `boost::compressed_pair` and what not.

```
template <class T>
void minimize(T f) {
}
```

Then you can pass it the result of `boost::bind`. Remember that `boost::bind` is actually a function template that returns some object of some type. So having `minimize` have a non-const reference parameter couldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are taking your template argument as a ref-to-non-const, so the temporary returend by boost::bind won't bind to it. So you can use it like:

```
template <class T>
T::result_type minimize(const T &f) {
}
```

But if you wanted to use this with your Functors as well, they would have to have a const operator(). So perhaps by value is better:

```
 template <class T>
 T::result_type minimize(T f) {
 }
```

I believe having the return be T::result_type will force a T to be a boost::function (rather than the complicated type bind returns), but I'm not 100%