# Signature for function taking boost::bind as an argument (boost::asio timer callback)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a wrapper method set_timer() that takes a time and callback (expressed using boost::bind) and sets up a deadline_timer to run that callback.

The callback is real simple at the moment:

```
void foo::callback(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    std::cout << "callback" << std::endl;
}
```

For set_timer() I have:

```
void foo::set_timer(boost::posix_time::ptime time,
                    boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> handler) {
    pimpl->t.expires_at(time);
    pimpl->t.async_wait(handler);
}
```

And I'm trying to call it from within the foo object for now:

```
set_timer(boost::posix_time::seconds(1), boost::bind (&foo::callback, this));
```

Error message when compiling is:

```
foo.cpp: In member function ‘void foo::run()’:
foo.cpp:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::set_timer(boost::posix_time::seconds, boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void(const boost::system::error_code&), foo>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<foo*> > >)’
src/foo_sdr.cpp:43: note: candidates are: void foo::set_timer(boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)>)
```

Looks like the signature is either much more complex or much simpler than I'm thinking.

I'd like to replace the callback signature with something like:

```
typedef std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> timer_callback_t;
```

I'm on CentOS 6.6 with gcc 4.4.7 and -std=gnu++0x, so no access to `auto`.

No luck working off [How do you pass boost::bind objects to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044703/how-do-you-pass-boostbind-objects-to-a-function) or [What is the return type of boost::bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412065/what-is-the-return-type-of-boostbind), and I don't understand what's different about my situation.

Comment: You need a placeholder (_1) for the argument to the callback method in your boost::bind.

Comment: Are you thinking `set_timer(boost::posix_time::seconds(1), boost::bind (&foo::callback, this, _1));`? That's not doing the trick. I'm thinking that `boost::asio::placeholders::error` needs to be in the signature.

Comment: you are correct, of course.

Comment: Doing `set_timer(boost::posix_time::seconds(1), boost::bind (&foo::callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));` results in a similar error message. The compiler error above tells me that I'm creating a much more complex signature with the `boost:bind()` call than is present in the receiving argument in `set_timer()`. There's some important concept I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the return type of `boost::bind` is an expression template, and much more complicated than a function type. It is, after all, not a function but a function *object* (complete with bound attribute values) of an on-the-fly synthesized type.

This type is implementation defined and you don't need to know it *as long as you make sure the resulting signature is congruent with the one you are trying to assign to*. Indeed, the handler **requires** a single unbound argument of type `error_code`, so add the placeholder as suggested in the comment:

```
boost::bind (&foo::callback, this, ai::placeholders::error)
```

A few general fixes, and a few more steps to make it self contained:

- `time_duration` is not convertible to `ptime`. Perhaps you wanted to say `expires_from_now` instead of `expires_at`. But in case you did want the latter, specify an absolute deadline:

  ```
  posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() + posix_time::seconds(1)
  ```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e83def8ef53fbe17)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace ai = boost::asio;

struct foo {

    ai::io_service svc;
    ai::deadline_timer t{svc};

    void callback(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        std::cout << "callback: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }

    void set_timer(boost::posix_time::ptime time, boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> handler) {
        t.expires_at(time);
        t.async_wait(handler);
    }

    void fornow() {
        set_timer(
                boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1),
                boost::bind (&foo::callback, this, ai::placeholders::error)
            );

        svc.run();
    }
};

int main() {
    foo o;
    o.fornow();
}
```

Prints after 1 second:

```
callback: Success
```

Comment: This works! I was convinced that the mismatch was due to `boost::bind()` that I didn't double-check my time types.